# Brownie map.json is empty need to restore it

Tags: brownie

My map.json got corrupted and i had build folder not in sync with github.

Is there a way to recreate the map.json for an already deployed contract?

```
File "brownie/_cli/__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 45, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "brownie/network/main.py", line 55, in connect
    p._load_deployments()
  File "brownie/project/main.py", line 372, in _load_deployments
    deployment_map = self._load_deployment_map()
  File "brownie/project/main.py", line 405, in _load_deployment_map
    deployment_map = json.load(fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Thank you